# List all components under a subnet AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

Is there anyway I can list all resources/components under a sub-net using boto-3?

I'm unable to find a method which gives me result I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *single* method that lists everything, but there are API calls to list each type of component.

For example, you could list EC2 instances, ENIs, Load Balancers, etc.

Actually, everything in a subnet will have an ENI associated with it, so you could start there. However, it's often not easy to determine the component that is linked to the ENI.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help from AWS documentation?https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#subnet

Comment: I want to know all the resources under subnet not only EC2 instances. So this would not help, thanks for your comment